# How do I install the Irix operating system over a network

Tags: sgi, irix

I just bought an Irix machine off of eBay. It had 2 hard drives. It has some weird variables from the last user. What programs can I use to Net install the irix operating system onto my computer?

Comment: Please do not ban me again. Just tell me any place where I should change anything, or if I should add any photos, more information, etc.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/sgi-irix-6.5-install-from-remote-linux-server/